# activity is not getting launched after tapping over imageview in widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to launch the activity when I tap over a widget `TextView` but some how I am not able to do that.
Here is my code.

```
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.safehub_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
  //  intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);


    PendingIntent pIntent  = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
              0, intent,0);

    Log.e("widget" , "clicking set");
   remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wFollowMeText, pIntent);

   ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, MyWidget.class); 

   AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

Comment: activities are unhealthy as lunch :S

Comment: today i gonna skip the dinner ;) so let me have the lunch